# Combining ARIMA model with regression

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have time series data about sales/day, but I also want to include other data (static/dynamic) to forecast the time series.

Is it possible to combine ARIMA model and regression models to achieve the goal?

Comment: [Related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225196/regression-or-time-series-model-to-predict-trend).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can either use an ARIMAX model, or a regression with ARIMA errors. Rob Hyndman explains the difference in his blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). In R, you can use the `forecast` package to fit regressions with ARIMA errors, or the `TSA` package to fit an ARIMAX model.